# Persist an entity with a user reference in Yesod?

Tags: json, haskell, yesod

I'm changing my existing Yesod application to run on a SQL backend instead of mongo. The generated table structure is more strict then the mongo backend. Foreign key references should be created correctly on insert.

```
postFeedingsR :: Handler RepJson
postFeedingsR  = do
  muser <- maybeAuth
  parsedFeeding <- parseJsonBody_ --get content as JSON
  let userId = getUserId muser
  let feedingWithUser = Feeding (feedingDate parsedFeeding) (feedingSide parsedFeeding) (feedingTime parsedFeeding) (feedingExcrements parsedFeeding) (feedingRemarks parsedFeeding) userId --should be linked to user..
  fid <- runDB $ insert feedingWithUser --store in database
  --runDB $ update fid [ FeedingUserId =. userId ] --Old mongo style of linking the feeding to the user
  sendResponseCreated $ FeedingR fid --return the id
```

I try to update the Entity I get from parseJsonBody with the user UID from the maybeAuth. However this gives me the following error:

```
No instance for (aeson-0.6.0.2:Data.Aeson.Types.Class.FromJSON
                   (FeedingGeneric backend0))
  arising from a use of `parseJsonBody_'
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for
  (aeson-0.6.0.2:Data.Aeson.Types.Class.FromJSON
     (FeedingGeneric backend0))
In a stmt of a 'do' block: parsedFeeding <- parseJsonBody_
In the expression:
  do { muser <- maybeAuth;
       parsedFeeding <- parseJsonBody_;
       let userId = getUserId muser;
       let feedingWithUser
             = Feeding
                 (feedingDate parsedFeeding)
                 (feedingSide parsedFeeding)
                 (feedingTime parsedFeeding)
                 (feedingExcrements parsedFeeding)
                 (feedingRemarks parsedFeeding)
                 userId;
       .... }
In an equation for `postFeedingsR':
    postFeedingsR
      = do { muser <- maybeAuth;
             parsedFeeding <- parseJsonBody_;
             let userId = ...;
             .... }
```

I'm not sure why this happens. Could anyone put me in the right direction to solve this?

Comment: fixed it myself by adding the following: `Entity uid u <- requireAuth` to get the users ID and added the function `addUserToFeeding uid Feeding {feedingDate=date, feedingSide=side, feedingTime=time, feedingExcrement                                                                                                    s=ex, feedingRemarks=remarks} = Feeding date side time ex remarks uid` to create the Feeding with associated user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by changing the auth line to:

```
Entity uid u <- requireAuth
```

and by adding the function:

```
addUserToFeeding :: UserId -> Feeding -> Feeding                                                                                                                                                            
addUserToFeeding uid Feeding {feedingDate=date, feedingSide=side, feedingTime=time, feedingExcrements=ex, feedingRemarks=remarks} = Feeding date side time ex remarks uid
```

to create a new Feeding with associated user. This Feeding can then be stored in the normal way in Yesod:

```
let feedingWithUser = addUserToFeeding uid parsedFeeding                                                                                                                                              
fid <- runDB $ insert feedingWithUser --store in database
```